# Suppose G is a group which has only one element a such that |a| = 2. Prove that xa = ax, for all x ∈ G.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I know the following are true.

1) There is an inverse of a
2) There is an identity element (e*a) = a

In this case, e = 1 and the inverse of a is 1/|2|. However, if a is the only element in G and a is |2|, wouldn't that imply that x can only be x=|2|, for x ∈ G?

I'm not quite sure how to begin the proof either, I'm used to starting with "ab" cases and a binary function and then working the case down to ab=ba.

Comment: Why is that the inverse of $a$? Also are you saying $a$ is idempotent or that $a$ is in fact the real number $|2|=2$?

Comment: Actually, I stand mistaken. I mistook the |a| as the absolute value instead of the cardinality. Sorry about that, I'm still very new to Group Theory.

Comment: ^It's not the cardinality. $a$ is just one element, so if we're talking about cardinality, that's just one. What $|a|$ means is the $order$ of $a$ in the group.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: what is the order of conjugate of a in G?

Answer (score 1):

Conjugate also has same order as of a.
Thus $xax^{-1}=a$, for all $x$ belongs to $G$ ,this implies $xa=ax$.